# A set of eight related to eight

Tags: knowledge, wordplay, language

The 36 words below comprise a set of eight related to eight, a set of seven related to seven, a set of six related to six, and so on.  Which word belongs to the set of one?

```
ABILITY       ALTO          ARCHING       BANANA        BONE          BOSC
BRAN          COMPUTER      CONFERENCE    CONY          CRAG          DENT
DOG           ENABLE        FILE          FLING         GLENDA        GLUE
GRASS         GUN           IMPOSE        JOE           LAZY          MODEL
MORE          NATURAL       NEON          PERCY         POLLOCK       RASH
SCRIPT        SECRET        SHIRLEY       STRING        VIAL          VISOR
```

(With apologies to the GCHQ Kristmas Kwiz / puzzle book compilers, with whom this puzzle format originates.)

Comment: When you say "related to eight", does that mean eight of the words are somehow actually related to the number 8?

Comment: I think the lack of clarity is probably deliberate.

Comment: Annoyingly, this seems to have the "Only Connect" feature that some words fit well in multiple groups. At any rate, I have ten things in what I am fairly sure is meant to be the group of 8 :-).

Comment: We've found a few possible options now for the set of four. Any comment on the partial answer, or are you waiting for everything to be finished?

Comment: Your set of 8 has 7 correct answers so far, and elimination isn't much fun, so rot13 for the 'wrong' member: (fgevat orybatf ryfrjurer.)  

I've clearly made the 7-set much too difficult, beyond the point of unfairness, and I should have realised this and corrected it.  Apologies.

The sets of 5, 4, 3, and 2 are now correct.  

Advice on the set of 6: (nyy ner zvffvat fbzrguvat va pbzzba.)

Comment: Is it worth adding a clue or two?

Comment: To resurrect this a little, I know what the missing group of 6 is and have a couple of candidates for the 1... The group of 7 is a struggle though (I know you describe it as very difficult, above...) Is the group of 7 related to rot13(Ebzna ahzrenyf)?

Answer (score 5):

**Partial answer - sets of 8, 5, 4(?), 3, 2 found so far**

One set of words is formed by

> relationship with the word SUPER: superscript, supercomputer, supernatural, superimpose, superstring, superglue, supermodel, supervisor. That's **eight** words, and apparently there's a film called *Super 8*.

We still need to find the sets of size **seven** and **six**

Another set is formed by

> relationship with the word JACKSON: Shirley Jackson, Joe Jackson, Percy Jackson, Glenda Jackson, Jackson Pollock. That's **five** words, and apparently there's a band called Jackson Five.

Another set is (possibly?) formed by

> relationship with the word TOP: top dog, top gun, top secret, top banana. That's **four** words, and apparently there's a band called Four Tops. (I'm very unsure about "top banana" though. Could also be "top file"?)

Another set is formed by

> relationship with the word TRI: trifling, trivial, trident. That's **three** words, and of course TRI connects with three.

Another set is formed by

> types of PEAR: conference pear, Bosc pear. That's **two** words, and pear sounds like PAIR which connects with two.

That leaves the following words remaining to be classified:

> `ABILITY       ALTO          ARCHING       ------        BONE          ----`
>  `BRAN          --------      ----------    CONY          CRAG          ----`
>  `---           ENABLE        FILE          -----         ------        ----`
>  `GRASS         ---           ------        ---           LAZY          -----`
>  `MORE          -------       NEON          -----         -------       RASH`
>  `------        ------        -------       ------        ----          -----`

Comment: There's more possibilities for your first group - this is the one Gareth referred to in his comment above (I have 10 possibles too...).

Comment: @Stiv I was trying to choose only the words that most clearly fit there (almost anything could be argued to fit there, given the usage of that word to mean "very" as well as various things in superhero fiction). That said, I just realised that I missed one, so I think this is the group of 8.

Comment: It may be worth noting explicitly that those sets (which, FWIW, are the same ones I found before I had to go off and do other things...) do indeed match their numbers in a certain sense.

Comment: @Gareth And just as you say that, I find another set which very definitely matches its number :-) But I can't see the number match for the 5 and 8 sets though?

Comment: Damn it, I saw rot13(GEVIVNY) and looked briefly for others but didn't find them because I'm a moron. Anyway, you want rot13(gur Wnpxfba Svir naq Fhcre 8).

Comment: I'm reserving judgement on your 4-group for now (strikes me as possibly a bit tenuous and more suited for a 7...) but your other groups match mine (excluding ambiguity for the 8's...). I'm also missing the 6's and 7's at present...

Comment: What about [Krypto the SuperDog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krypto)?

Comment: @JMP As I said, you can put "super" in front of pretty much anything if you allow stuff from superhero fiction and the usage of "super" as an adverb meaning "very". I just chose the words that *most clearly* fit with it, which happened to be exactly 8 words.

Comment: @Randal'Thor A possible alternate set of four: rot13[Sbhe Gbcf (onaq): gbc onanan, gbc qbt, gbc tha, gbc frperg]

Comment: @hagfy I've edited with your suggestion, but still very unsure about banana there.

Comment: @tom I thought of over and under, but couldn't get enough words to fit with that ...

Comment: @tom I did search it on Google ... it just didn't seem very ... notable or well-known? Might be a regional thing, I guess.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - here banana makes a well known idiom, but file does not,... as you say probably a regional thing

Comment: Another option for 4: rot13 [nqq q, gur sbhegu yrggre, gb obar, oena, svyr, naq zber]

Comment: Here's another idea for 4, but I'm not too familiar with it to know for certain rot13(Snanfgvp Sbhe? Errq Evpuneqf - Tenff, Gur Guvat - Pent (Ebpx)?)

Comment: @HerbWolfe - I like you idea for 4, but I think enable also works..

Comment: @tom But because enable isn't a four letter word?

Comment: Maybe seven has to do with rot13(FR7RA? Frira qrnqyl fvaf - Fybgu = Ynml, Tyhggbal = Zber)

Comment: @VirtualValentin I thought of that, but couldn't get enough of the words to fit it for seven.

Comment: 'grass' would also fit in the group of eight. Again this is a regional thing, but this expression was very very well known some years ago where I am based. -- ok not sure how helpful this is, but just in case...